# C# modifying DataRow array reference in parallel.foreach , Why code runs correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

This is not exactly what I did with my code but it should represent the scenario of swapping array reference. I am not sure if the type of the array matters at all but still I specified it in the title.

1. Declare some DataRow arrays outside of loop. name them Array1, Array2 ... ArrayX etc
2. Array1 = Array2 or Array1 = Array3 ... or Array1 = ArrayX depending on the iteration variable
3. Do something with Array1

Code would be like this:

```
void Somefunction()
{
    int indices[];
    for (int i = 0; i < threadamount; ++i)
    {
        indices[i] = i;
    }

    DataRow[] Array1, Array2, Array3;
    //assign something to these arrays
    //...
    //end of assigning stuff

    Parallel.ForEach<int>(indices, index =>
    {
        if(index == 2)
           Array1 = Array2;
        else if(index == 3)
           Array1 = Array3;

        //do stuff with Array1

     });
 }
```

So back to the question. It seems that the code is run on all the arrays (correctly assigning Array2 / Array3 to Array1 in other threads) without race condition.

Why is that? I thought I would have to create a new variable inside the loop but no. Is it because it actually creates a copy of reference of Array1 for each thread? And the reference Array1 in each thread are actually different objects?

PS: this is my first question on here so I hope I did not make any mistake :p
I did read some other questions before trying to post this up here but they don't really answer my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mistaken, and there *are* problems.

I modified your code to test if `Array1` is changed after a thread has set it, and it turns out that it *is* sometimes changed.

The following code will print "Error!" if `Array1` is changed. On my system, it prints "Error" several times on either Release or Debug builds (quad core processor).

The results differ for each run (what you'd expect for a race condition):

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Somefunction();
        }

        static void Somefunction()
        {
            int threadamount = 100;
            int[] indices = new int[threadamount];
            for (int i = 0; i < threadamount; ++i)
            {
                indices[i] = i;
            }

            int[] Array1 = new int[1],
                  Array2 = new int[2],
                  Array3 = new int[3];

            Parallel.ForEach<int>(indices, index =>
            {
                if (index == 2)
                    Array1 = Array2;
                else if (index == 3)
                    Array1 = Array3;

                int[] test = Array1;
                Console.WriteLine(Array1.Length);

                if (!ReferenceEquals(test, Array1))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error!");
                }
             });
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing the reference is exactly what I wanted.
The problem is, I am doing a lot of stuff with Array1 and I'm not certain if that reference is changed in the middle of the loop after it is assigned the new reference.

EDIT: never mind that, I see it now. So I do have to create a new object after all.